# Abnormal shrinkage of the eyeball

Tags: eye, terminology, anatomy, opthalmology

Is there a condition which describes an abnormal shrinkage of the eyeball?

That is, a counterpart to [buphthalmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buphthalmos) (an abnormal enlargement of the eyeball).

Comment: Aging, genetics. Maybe dehydration and a lack of sleep?  http://www.symptomsofdehydration.com/  If it continued to be a problem I would advise such a person to see a doctor.

Comment: One eyeball or both? Sudden or long-term?

Answer (score 2):

- **Atrophia bulbi** (*with shrinkage*)

  It occurs *with shrinkage* and also *without shrinkage*. In *without shrinkage*, generally the eye is of normal size, but the globe can be enlarged due to glaucoma. In *with shrinkage*, the globe becomes soft,small and partially collapsed. Atrophy is present in the intraocular tissues but the relationship between the tissues are relatively intact.The horizontal and verical rectal muscles are pulled off which gives the globe a cuboid-like appearance rather than a spherical one. The intraocular pressure (IOP) is decreased. The anterior chamber collapses and the cornea becomes edematous and opacified.
- **Phthisis bulbi**

  It is also called as *atrophia bulbi with disorganization*. The globe becomes small, mostly under an average diameter of 16-19 mm(noraml is 24-26 mm). The sclera becomes thickened and the cornea is opacified. Intraocular ossification(bone-formation) may also occur. The bowman layer, lens and retina are calcified. Proliferation and metaplasia of the retinal pigment epithelium (RPE) leads to drusen formation of the eye.

> [image]
> [Source [4](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=g8U0AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+massachusetts+eye&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyv_ubtsvbAhVBpZQKHUF-DPMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=The%20massachusetts%20eye&f=false)]

---

**References:**

1: [AMERICAN ACADEMY OF OPHTHALMOLOGY](https://www.aao.org/bcscsnippetdetail.aspx?id=8ede24ac-d9bc-4ea8-8e19-38e73830cea6)

2: [Essentials of Ophthalmology
By Neil J. Friedman, Peter K. Kaiser](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=m-AMO4gkTtMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Essentials+of+ophthalmology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiupa_rtMvbAhXEKY8KHamzCnQQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Essentials%20of%20ophthalmology&f=false)

3: [Ocular Pathology
By Myron Yanoff, Joseph William Sassani](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=V9lV7iSrJvEC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Ocular+pathology&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvv7LFtcvbAhWMRY8KHd2aDEEQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=Ocular%20pathology&f=false)

4: [The Massachusetts Eye and Ear Infirmary Illustrated Manual of Ophthalmology 
    ...By Neil J.      Friedman, Peter K. Kaiser, Roberto Pineda II](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=g8U0AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=The+massachusetts+eye&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyv_ubtsvbAhVBpZQKHUF-DPMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=The%20massachusetts%20eye&f=false)

5: [Pathology of the Eye
By G.O.H. Naumann, D.J. Apple](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=yI_TBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Pathology+of+the+eye&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWl5fxtsvbAhXGQo8KHUGaBAsQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=Pathology%20of%20the%20eye&f=false)